# Audio output comes through my input device

Tags: audio, skype

Whilst using Skype/TS all of my computers outputs are being sent as my input. What I've tried so far:

> - Turning it on and off again
> - Disabling sound mixer
> - Uninstalling realtek
> - Made sure my default devices are correct
> - Made sure my headset is plugged in correctly
> - Tried a different headset
> - Made sure listen to device was off
> - Reinstalled drivers

I've recently bought a new computer and I've only noticed the problem since then. Is there something I've missed that I should check and are there any hardware related fixes I should check?

I wasn't sure which section to put it in so I hope this is okay

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be able to set your Skype output devices in (Windows) Tools -> Options -> Audio settings, or (Linux) Options -> Sound Devices -> Open _(sound driver)_ Volume Control.

Comment: I've done that and the devices are set correctly but it's still not working.

Comment: In that case what is telling you that "_all of my computers outputs are being sent as my input_"?

Comment: When I'm in a call for example, any sounds that are made are put through my mic. I know it's not because it's too close either as it's not a muffled sound but rather the direct audio.

Comment: I would not expect a microphone to give a clear sound when used as a speaker. Is it external or a laptop's internal microphone? If external, then you may be using the wrong type of jack plug.